# gapi.client.gmail.users.labels.create gives invalidArgument error

Tags: javascript, gmail-api

I am working on creating labels using **JavaScript** **Gmail API**.

```
function createLabel(userId, newLabelName, callback) {
var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.labels.create({
'userId': userId,
'label': {'name': newLabelName}
});
request.execute(callback);}
```

> This is the code of [Developer API Example](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/create)

I am able to authenticate and even I'll get the label list but while creating the label I am getting the below error.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalidArgument",
    "message": "Invalid request"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid request"
 }
}
```

But when I am using the [Try It](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/create#try-it) example It's working but only difference is it's do the POST request with key={Your auth key} which the example provided won't attach that part to URL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The data you send should be in the `resource`-parameter, and `labelListVisibility` and `messageListVisibility` are also mandatory fields:

```
function createLabel(userId, newLabelName, callback) {
  gapi.client.gmail.users.labels.create({
    userId: userId,
    resource: {
      name: newLabelName,
      labelListVisibility: 'labelShow',
      messageListVisibility: 'show'
    }
  }).execute(callback);
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! I also had the same issue. 
If was following Google documentation, but it's clear wrong! 
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/create?authuser=1

Answer (score 0):

And you can't specify the id of the label, it's an immutable parameter, google create it for us, but you can get it after the creation with

```
async function createLabel(gmail, name) {
  const res = await gmail.users.labels.create({
    userId: 'me',
    requestBody: {
        name: name,
        messageListVisibility: 'show',
        labelListVisibility: 'labelShow',
        type: 'user',
    },
  });

  console.log(res.data.id);
}
```